# Do the relay NC NO pins have different capacities?

Tags: arduino

I bought a relay for arduino and came 2 specs.

```
10A 250VAC
10A 125VAC
JQC3F-05VDC-C
```

I did not understand why "10A 125VAC", as already reported "10A 250VAC".
Is the capacity different for NC and NO? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [datasheet](https://voron.ua/files/pdf/relay/JQC-3F(T73).pdf) of the relay.

Your relay is fine for:
10A 250VAC
10A 30VDC

Comment: Thanks Friend! I think this relay is fake because I'm only connecting 0.6Amp. and in Brazil-RN is 220VAC. Once it is triggered, it no longer shuts down. I measured with multimeter and it is correct.